# Swift Adding Zeros to Doubles Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that randomly gets a coin put into it (denominations: 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25). The array is a Double array. It seems to work, but at times values get added that look like this:

```
[0.050000000000000003]
[0.050000000000000003, 0.01]
[0.050000000000000003, 0.01, 0.10000000000000001]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to have these extra zeros show up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Cue the classic answer: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You could use an enum instead of raw numbers.enum Coins: Int {
 static var denominator = 100;
 case pence = 1;
 case five = 5;
 case ten = 10;
 case quarter = 25;
}

Comment: All great answers. Thank you so much.